# Cant view infopath form after submit in sharepoint list

Tags: 2010, infopath

I publish Infopath forms to a SharePoint Library. The forms are being sent to the Email recipients but can't be viewed in the SharePoint library.

I use a submit button and a SharePoint data connection.

Please advise

p.s i use SP 10

Answer (score 0):

Need more information.

Do you mean a copy of the form is being sent to the email recipent/also uploaded to the form library and the same recient cannot view the form when they navigate to the library. ---- If so, ensure they have appropriate permissions to view the items (either add the recipent indivisually or add the appropriate AD group)

You mentioned you are using a SP Data Connection ---- I am assuming you are saving this in a connnection libary, ensure it has been approved.

Hope it helps